# Visual Studio C# Web Form, with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am creating a webform, utilizing Bootstrap 4 in conjunction with Asp.net

I am trying to get all the text boxes to align in the same position across rows. In the attached picture, I would like to get the text boxes aligned with the black lines.  I am racking my brain over this, some help would be greatly appreciated!

I am attaching a snippet of my code and an image. Thank you!

[Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNCIi.png)

```
            <div class="form-group col-auto">
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Phone/Ext"></asp:Label>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group col-auto">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" CssClass="form-conrtol"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-inline mt-2">
            <div class="form-group col-auto">
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="E-Mail"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-auto">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass="form-conrtol"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-auto">
                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Cost Center"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-auto">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDeptCc" runat="server" CssClass="form-conrtol"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Have you checked the official documentation for Bootstrap 4 Grids? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ 
If I understand correctly you want 4 columns and 5 rows,  same width for each column. Or if you want varying width for labels and textboxes than you want 2 column only to align to the black line in the picture. There are example codes on the link.

Comment: you can use <div class=""row">

Comment: Anyway we probably need to see a bit more of the HTML surround these form fields to be able to understand how the layout is being build. We need a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thanks.